# Git commands require sudo on OSX

Tags: macos, git, sudo

I've moved back from my work MBP to my home MBP. The work one allowed to run git commands without the need for sudo. But I'm finding this is a requirement on my home machine.

I would prefer to be able to run `git` commands without `sudo`.

I looked at the git commands in `/usr/bin`, and they all have `rwxr-xr-x` (`755`), and are owned by `root` and group `wheel`. I suppose I could change this to `rwxrwxrwx` (`777`), but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I'm thinking of adding my user to the `wheel` group; but would there be other side effects?

Comment: If the commands have the execute bit set for world (and they do), then changing your group is not a solution.

Comment: You might want to check out my answer @ [Can't run “git” without sudo on OS X](http://superuser.com/a/1141913/659669)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The permission on the `git` executable are fine; there is no reason you should need to change that, or change your group.

It's more likely that the permissions on your Git checkout are wrong. If you accidentally checked it out with something like `sudo git clone ssh://user@host/project.git`, or at some point you performed some kind of operation in the repository that caused some files to be owned by root, `git` running under your account won't be able to write to those files.

Most likely, what you need to do is `chown -R <user> myproject` in order to make your project owned by your own user account, rather than root.

Comment: Thanks Brian. It turns out the .git directory (which I created using git init) was owned by root. Applied the chown (which required sudo, of course) and was able to perform git commands without sudo. (yay)

Comment: thanks that was it! i'd also add that you can check who's the owner with: "ls -al"

Answer (score 4):

If you were prompted like this:

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

And then you ran:

```
sudo git init .
```

After updating xcode license.  Just remove the init and re-init w/o sudo

```
sudo rm -rf .git
git init .
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: I chose this solution as it is the fastest and the project was new, but maybe you should add some warning for users who may copy paste this command without realising they will delete their earlier versions of files?